# Migration from Struts1 to Struts2

Tags: struts2

I have my application in Struts1 and I have used Dispatch action in all my actions. Please tell me now how do I Shift to struts 2 and what are the modifications that should be made to change all my actions and form beans.

Comment: Read the **[Migration Guide : Struts 1 to Struts 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20120118163808/http://struts.apache.org/2.2.3.1/docs/migration-guide.html)**

Answer (score 6):

I will suggest you this document series:

- http://www.infoq.com/articles/converting-struts-2-part1
- http://www.infoq.com/articles/migrating-struts-2-part2

First link explains the topic and there is an example at second link. I wrote below an explanation taken from there:

*Configuring the framework*

The first, and most important configuration, is the one that enables the web application framework within the servlet containers web.xml file.

The configuration that everyone should be familiar with for Struts is:

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>config</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

For Struts2 there are very few changes. The most significant is that the dispatcher has been changed from a servlet to a servlet filter. The configuration is just as easy as for a servlet, and shown here:

```
<filter>
<filter-name>webwork</filter-name>
<filter-class>
    org.apache.struts.action2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher
</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>webwork</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

*Deconstructing the Actions*

In the request walk-through we spoke about some of the differences between Struts and Struts2 from a high level. Let's take it a step deeper now, and look at the differences between the structures of the actions in each framework.

Let's first review the general structure of the Struts action. The general form of the Struts action looks like this:

public class MyAction extends Action {
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping,
                                 ActionForm form,
                                 HttpServletRequest request,
                                 HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        // do the work
        return (mapping.findForward("success"));
    }
}

When implementing a Struts action, you need to be aware of the following items:

- All actions have to extend the Action base class.
- All actions have to be thread-safe, as only a single action instance is created.
- Because the actions have to be thread-safe, all the objects that may be needed in the processing of the action are passed in the method signature.
- The name of the method that is invoked for the processing of the action is "execute" (there is a DispatchAction class available in Struts which can re-route the method to be executed to another method in the same action, however the initial entry point from the framework into the action is still the "execute" method).
- An ActionForward result is returned using a method from the ActionMapping class, most commonly via the "findForward" method call.

In contrast, the Struts2 action provides a much simpler implementation. Here's what it looks like:

```
public class MyAction {
   public String execute() throws Exception {
        // do the work
        return "success";
   }
}
```

The first thing you may have noticed is that the action doesn't extend any classes or interfaces. In fact, it goes further than this. By convention, the method invoked in the processing of an action is the "execute" method - but it doesn't have to be. Any method that follows the method signature public String methodName() can be invoked through configuration.

Finally, and perhaps the most revolutionary difference from the original Struts implementation, is that the method invoked in the processing of an action (the "execute" method) has no parameter. So how do you get access to the objects that you need to work with? The answer lies in the "inversion of control" or "dependency injection" pattern (for more information Martin Fowler has an informative article at http://www.martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html). The Spring Framework has popularized this pattern, however, the predecessor to Struts2 (WebWork) started using the pattern around the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You *may* use [dynamic method invocation](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/action-configuration.html#ActionConfiguration-DynamicMethodInvocation) to vaguely-mimic the old `DispatchAction`-style "pass in the method name" functionality (or you could write an interceptor that used a parameter to do much the same thing).

There are no "form beans" per se in Struts 2, although you can implement `ModelDriven` ([some docs](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/model-driven-interceptor.html)) and it *sort*-of works like a form bean.

All JSPs will need to be re-written, but only if you're using the Struts 1 tags. If you used only JSTL tags, you *may* not need to, it'd depend.

The link provided by Ischin is a good place to start getting more details.

Answer (score 0):

- For the Struts 2.x: Make the dispatcher action filter as `*.action`
- For the struts 1.x: Make the action filter as `*.do .`