# Struts 1 to Struts 2 :: JSP conversion

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts-1, struts-tags

We have a Struts 1 Application and looking to upgrade it to Struts 2 so out of all the possible options we are trying below that addresses our priority

1. Adding a Struts 2 Strut 1 plugin that acts as a wrapper for all our action classes
2. Change the JSP's to Struts 2 Tags (which had to be done in either case but choose to do this first
3. After converting all the JSP's we will do a module wise conversion of our Action classes based on certain timing latter on.

We have done good research and everything mentioned above just works in our POC.

Converting JSP tags seems more mechanical, however we are loosing time in finding what tags to be replaced by which and which attribute. I had a hard time finding on internet. So any person who has done this earlier can you share with me or any program that converts all my JSP to corresponding struts 2 tags.

This will help save us some time if any one here has done research earlier of any tips for getting this up quickly?

Comment: Ain't yet mechanical? If you have JSTL code you could keep the JSTL that works fine with the Struts2 framework.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/a/20130845/573032

Comment: JSTL works fine.. but e.g. logic:iterate tag we had used lot of attributes so it needs to be replaced with s:iterator.. So I'm try to find is there some guide or documentation which tag to be changed with which one in version 2 of struts

Comment: There is no automated conversion that I am aware of. You should replace all S1 tags/functionality in the JSP pages.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Struts 1 plugin](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/struts-1-plugin.html)

   > The Struts 1 plugin allows you to use existing Struts 1 Actions and
   >   ActionForms in Struts 2 applications.
   >
   > This plugin provides a generic Struts 2 Action class to wrap an
   >   existing Struts 1 Action, org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action. The
   >   wrapper class provides the expected calls to the legacy Struts 1
   >   Action and ActionForm, converting incoming and outgoing objects into
   >   the expected forms. It works by using the scoped model driven
   >   technique that uses a single Object as the model for every page, very
   >   similar to how the Struts 1 ActionForm works. The plugin also provides
   >   several interceptors to emulate Struts 1 logic:
   >
   > ```
   > org.apache.struts2.s1.ActionFormValidatorInterceptor - Integrates the validation of ActionForms into the workflow of Struts 2
   > org.apache.struts2.s1.ActionFormResetInterceptor - Calls the reset() method on any discovered ActionForms
   > ```
2. No, there are no tools to do that. There is a request ([JIRA WW-2157](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2157)) to create one but I doubt we will see it soon. 
   However, according to a [JIRA comment](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-2157?focusedCommentId=12824486&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-12824486), some of the S1 Tags should keep working.
3. No need to do it (thanks to the plugin), but it would be nice. Good luck with that...

Comment: thanks for reply... Third point - We want to completely get rid of struts 1 so will be doing it.. May be is there any guide that saves our time of researching....