# Struts1 migration to Struts 2

Tags: struts2

I am my migrating my Struts 1.1 application to Struts 2.1.
I know that in struts 1 all action urls have .do eg
`myLoginAction.do`
So can Struts 2 also have action with .do extension?
If yes what is the correct way to that?
Need step by step solution.

Comment: You should migrate from Struts 1.1 to Struts 2.3.16.1. Otherwise, is a waste of time

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/20127369/573032

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `struts.action.extension` to define acceptable multiple patterns.

The following constant allows actions with the suffixes of "", ".action", or ".do".

```
<constant name="struts.action.extension" value=",action,do" />
```