# Can Struts 2.3 be used with Struts 1.3?

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

we have 2 applications (Say AppA and AppB) that use Struts 1.3.

I want to upgrade AppB to use struts 2.3, however I cannot make changes to AppA so it will have to remain in Struts 1.3.

The problem is that AppB has some dependencies on AppA such as extending Actions classes, tag classes, filters, etc..

Is Struts backward compatible?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Struts 2 migration with Struts 1 Code Base](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127369/struts-2-migration-with-struts-1-code-base)

Comment: No, you can't. S1 and S2 are totally different frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not exactly. However, you can have both libraries running and responding to separate paths. Do this in your web.xml servlet mapping. For example: /struts1/*.do and /*.do

Unfortunately, this will not allow you to extend Actions from struts1 in struts 2. (You probably wouldn't want to, anyway.)

You can add a plugin to Struts2 apps to run Struts1 Actions. This might be the fastest way to get your situation working. More information here: https://struts.apache.org/docs/struts-1-plugin.html

Assuming you can't change AppA, the next best option is to just create new Struts2 base classes in AppB. Hopefully, you can crib liberally from AppA.

Comment: Thank you Barett, will follow your advice.

Comment: Can you elaborate about fasted way to get your situation working? The link you used explained nothing.