# Correct syntax to convert struts1 logic tag to Struts2 if tag

Tags: jsp, struts2, struts, jsp-tags, ognl

I am working on migrating struts to struts2 application and I am not sure if I have the correct syntax. I have this struts1 logic tag used:

```
<logic:equal name="myForm" property="fromWhere"
    scope="request" value="search">
<app:pageBanner/>
```

And I have converted this to Struts2 as followed:

```
<s:if test="%{myForm.fromWhere == \"search\"}">
```

My doubt is in the use of the name="myForm" along with the property="fromWhere" inside the if tag.

I have reviewed most websites that come up in Google when you search for Migrating Struts1 to Struts2, Struts2 tags, and a few more so if anyone knows of sites providing more details on how to work with this tags including examples, or help with migrating from struts1 to struts2, please post them along. I will appreciate it.

Thank you for taking time to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `s:if` tag you shouldn't use `the name="myForm" along with the property="fromWhere"`. The correct syntax

```jsp
<s:if test="myForm.fromWhere == 'search'">
```

The `myForm` should be an action class variable that have a public getter  `getMyForm()` to access this variable from the view and evaluate the OGNL expression in the `test` attribute.

Examples you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130845/573032).

Comment: Roman, thanks for the answer. In your correct sytanx example, you are using the myForm along with the property which contradicts your advice. Was that a typo?

Comment: No, I didn't get actually what contradicts for?

Comment: you said inside the s:if tag not to use the name="myForm" along with the property. And you said the correct Syntax is:   <s:if test="myForm.fromwhere == 'search'"> but you are using myForm inside the if tag. That was what I meant it was contradictory. Your example is pretty similar to what I am using above.

Comment: That's right the `s:if` tag doesn't have `name` attribute nor `property` attribute.

Comment: That clarifies what I was doing. Thanks again for taking the time to answer and thanks for the examples.

Comment: Sorry Roman, I checked it as resolved with your answer but it wouldn't let me upvote. However, I did it today. I have another question I will be creating shortly. I hope you are around to see it.

Comment: @Richard The rule is simple if you accept the answer you should also upvote it, if you don't have enough rep for this in the future when you got rep return back and upwote. Believe me it will help you to progress on SO.