# According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute name is mandatory for tag text

Tags: jsp, struts2

I am new to Struts2. I got stuck with an issue:

> ```
> According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute name is mandatory for tag text
> ```

**Hi my JSP file is**

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="html"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2 style="color:red;"><% if(request.getParameter("msg")!=null) {
    out.println(request.getParameter("msg"));
}%></h2>
    <h1 class="welcome">Login To Your Account</h1>
    <div style="align-items: center;margin-left:200px;font-size:20px;white-space:pre;">
    <html:form action="/loginsuccess">
    UserName <html:text style="height:30px;width:300px;padding:10px;" property="username" /><br><br>
    PassWord  <html:password style="height:30px;width:300px;padding:10px;" property="password"/><br><br>
    <input type ="submit" value="Log in" /><br><br>
    New User ? <a href="signup.jsp">Signup</a>
    </html:form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

so this is giving me an error

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /login.jsp (line: 44, column: 10) According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute name is mandatory for tag text
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.jspError(ErrorDispatcher.java:237)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:859)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:895)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1538)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2427)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2433)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:474)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2375)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1817)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:657)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:96)
```

Should i add anything more to the text tag?

Comment: For the name tag,only property attribute is mandatory,but still you can give this a try

Comment: @user7294900 It won't work, the [text tag](http://struts.apache.org/docs/text.html) is used to render i18n messages.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal The name attribute is mandatory.

Comment: Which part of the error you didn't understand?

Comment: @RomanC I was referring to the given link https://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/html/text.html for taglib definition.Could you please provide the link  to the one for reference.

Comment: @ShivamAggarwal This link is obsolete, you should read my answer to understand why and I've also posted a link in my previous [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44898899/573032#comment76801294_44898899).

Comment: sure,thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The taglib definition is for Struts2, but the JSP code is for Struts1. You can't substitute TLD from one framework to another, so the code won't work.

In Struts2 we usually name the prefix with `s:` to distinguish between frameworks, but you can use old preifix if you like it, nevertheless the code should be rewritten to use the new tag library.

```
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="html"%>
```

If you need help migrating Struts1 application to Struts2 you should read [Migration from Struts 1 to Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130845/573032).