# TLDs in Struts2

Tags: struts2

I am working on migration project where legacy code(Struts1) needs to be migrated to Struts2. I want to know how to convert tld files to Struts2.

**TLD Files**

1) struts-html.tld

2) struts-logic.tld

3) c.tld

4) bdb.tld

Here, bdb.tld is custom tld file which has custom tags

Edit1: It is marked as duplicate of [Migration from Struts 1 to Struts 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127369/migration-from-struts-1-to-struts-2/20130845#20130845). But migration of tlds is not explained in that post.

Comment: What do you mean, convert TLD files? There's essentially zero similarity between S1 and S2--you don't "convert", you write.

Comment: @DaveNewton: How can I write struts-html.tld,struts-logic.tld? Those are provided by framework. Custom tlds like bdb.tld can be re-written.

Comment: You don’t. Those TLDs are S1-specific and have no meaning in S2.

Comment: TLD files should be removed FIY.