# Recommendation migrating to struts 2.x from struts 1.2?

Tags: struts2, struts, struts-1

I'm been tasked to migrate two enterprise applications (Java 7/JSP/Web 2.4) from Struts 1.2 to any version of Struts 2.x.  The struts.apache site states Struts 2.5.20 is the "best available".  Is there any recommendations/opposition on going all the way to 2.5.20 or should I stick with the latest prior version of 2.3.37?  I'd appreciate any advice from those who have already been though this.

I will develop using Rational Application Developer 9.5.0.2.

Update:  I just discovered, if you plan to use the struts2-struts1-plugin for your migration, 2.5 will not support this plugin.  The latest release where this plugin is supported is 2.3.37.

Comment: I can't think of any valid reason to deliberately use the 2.3 series (first released ~2012) for new app development. Unrelated, but I'd recommend making darn sure the stakeholders understand what's involved in porting what must be 10-15 year-old projects to an entirely different framework.

Comment: If it isn't a version issue then https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130845/573032