# [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/cert/X509Certificate

Tags: java, spring, struts, x509, applicationcontext

I've been stuck on this a little while.  War file compiles fine, classes seem to be there, not sure what is causing this issue. The application will not run and returns a 404 error.

It started when I tried updating struts and spring .jar files.  It's an old application that I took over and was severely out of date.  Trying to get it to a good place security wise, and I can't get past this deployment error.

Any direction someone could point me in would be greatly appreciated.

```
21-Oct-2022 14:39:18.916 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-42] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener]
        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/cert/X509Certificate
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:414)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:217)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:188)
                at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:125)
                at org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlWebApplicationContext.java:94)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:126)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:614)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:514)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
                at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4689)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5155)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:743)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:719)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:970)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
                at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
                at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
        Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/security/cert/X509Certificate
```

Comment: Which versions of struts and spring do you use after upgrading and what java version do you use?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All I wanted to do was upgrade struts from 2.3.37 to 2.5.30, and in doing so my application won't load.  I don't get any compilation errors.

Comment: What version of Java? What are you running it on?

Comment: openjdk version "1.8.0_345"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_345-b01)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.345-b01, mixed mode)

Comment: It is almost impossible for the same reason see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20130845/573032).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It was a .jar file conflict.  I had a duplicate spring jar file that was the wrong version.  It was sprint-security-core-4.1.5.RELEASE.  Once I removed that the application loaded as expected.