java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport
I have the following code in a JSP file for the tags which is included in all of my JSP files at the top:
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%> 
 
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    prefix="sec"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springmodules.org/tags/commons-validator"
    prefix="v"%>
<html:xhtml />
<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

Since I recently migrated from Spring 5.X to Spring 6, I've changed the above to the following as per Jakarta Specification of 3.0 listed here:
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%> 

<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="jakarta.tags.functions" prefix="fn"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"
    prefix="sec"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springmodules.org/tags/commons-validator"
    prefix="v"%>
<html:xhtml />

<c:set var="ctx" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}" />

However, I still keep on getting following error while accessing a JSP page.
[INFO] SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [myapp] in context with path [/myapp] threw exception [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/jsp/tagext/BodyTagSupport] with root cause
[INFO] java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.jsp.tagext.BodyTagSupport

Here are few relevant things from my pom.xml:
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>10.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
   </dependency>
    

    

I'm using Tomcat 10.1.25 here to start the above app. Is there anything I need to doublecheck or doing wrong? I have looked at other posts similar to this and I seem to be satisfying what's mentioned over there.
Note: Struts is not used in the app anymore even though I have some declarations in the app and I will be removing the remnants after this issue is fixed.

Tomcat 10.1 uses servlet specification 6 and therefore has no more javax provided. I am guessing the issue is some outdated library that still relies on javax imports in its  code - go through all your libraries and update them

I believe these outdate libraries might be coming from the struts related stuff which I'm no longer using?

Also what is "Tomcat 10.1.45"? Is this a typo?

Yes, I have been using 10.1.25. Edited my post with correct version.

Then you should update it using my answer below. Also, don't forget to accept and upvote it.

If you want to comply to Jakarta Pages specification then you should remove old Struts and Display tag library definitions:
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" prefix="logic"%> 

<%@ taglib uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" prefix="display"%>


And, you should remove runtime and compile dependencies on them.
Remove tags usage from JSP pages such as
<html:xhtml />

Also if you are using Jakarta EE 10 then you should pick up the latest 2024-07-12 Tomcat 10.1.26 Released:

The Apache Tomcat Project is proud to announce the release of version 10.1.26 of Apache Tomcat. This release implements specifications that are part of the Jakarta EE 10 platform.


Is <html:xhtml /> something that will go away with struts stuff as well? I don't understand what's the purpose of <html:xhtml /> in there as I am not the one who created it many years ago.

Question #2:  When you say If you want to comply to Jakarta Standard Tag Library 3.0 specification then you should remove old JSTL, I have already renamed java.sun.com taglib URIs to new jakarta.tags.* URNs as shown in my post. Did you also mean there is a similar replacement for struts as well that I currently have it included ?

contd ...  The reason I'm asking is because I have one project where there is no struts used and another project where struts is used. So the project containing some of the pom declarations above is used as a dependency with two projects (one where struts is no longer used but remnants are there which is the case with above scenario and another project, where struts is still used and I have made use of web legacy struts to keep it functional after upgrade from Spring 5.x to Spring 6)

Yes, but you didn't remove all dependencies on it. The link you have posted has a tutorial, so you can learn basics to use JSTL in the Jakarta EE. I don't care whether you use Struts or not in your project but you should remove dependencies on it because current version of struts is not jakarta-ee compatible. Sooner or later Struts 7  will be released, then you can use it with Spring 6. But your legacy Struts version is deprecated decades ago and you still didn't upgrade it to the newer version, so you can't use it in the current softwares. So, you have only one option to remove it at all.

Anyway you can't use the same pom declarations with two projects. Until both project libraries have support for Jakarta EE spec. Struts1 is EOL, so it will never support Jakarta EE latest version. However, the version 1.0 is Jakarta Struts edition (2 decades ago). You can keep old Struts app as a  separate app, coz integrating both is not recommended. See my answer here.

The specification is linked in the details of the document.

Is there a documentation showing what will be the JSTL equivalent of the struts tags which are using <%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" prefix="html"%> , basically, I have <html:submit/> , <html:messages/> , <html:javascript /> tags in use which I am trying to get rid of. I have gotten hold of the ones starting withbeanandlogic` and wondering about the above one.

No, you can easily find old docs for Struts1 tags. If you read abovelinked answer: "the step 3 is the most difficult", and you should rewrite tags instead of finding equivalents in JSTL. But the problem is the target framework which is the taglib is written for using in apps. Struts2 has its own taglib that cover JSTL even if the framework has support for it

Are you referring to the step3 answer in this comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78771251/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-javax-servlet-jsp-tagext-bodytagsupport/78772223?noredirect=1#comment138894474_78772223
If yes, then I believe you are referring to InfoQ Migration Guide: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127369/migration-from-struts-1-to-struts-2/20130845#20130845) which is Struts 2 based. So I'm little confused here as I'm using Struts 1. Thanks !

You cannot use Struts 1 if you use Jakarta EE in your application. You have options: 1. Migrate your JSPs to Struts2; 2. Rewrite Struts tags to other framework like Spring MVC, etc.; 3. Write REST API and create a frontend for it in JavaScript. Struts 1 is EOL, so it cannot be used in the applications.

Yes, I'm not using struts anymore. Just getting rid of all the tags in the JSP that are still in use.

Did you want to say Struts 1? Not using Struts won't get rid of your problems.

Yup, Struts 1.  The API part is already all Spring MVC based and it's just that I need to get rid of all the struts tags from the JSP.

It requires to have Struts 1 skills. Without that you have to start from scratch again.
